# how to insert records for top 10 enteries only

Tags: mysql, sql

I have gathered top 10 users for specific task. Using the query given below.

```
$sqlsum=mysql_query("SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
    `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Now , I need to award bonues to the top 10 gathered users only. I am not getting the idea , on how to write query for this purpose.

I need to update one field in  tablename = user , field name = bonus .

Kindly guide.

Comment: Please show your table format . . . or at least what the code would look like to add any "bonus".

Comment: @GordonLinoff are you not understanding what he wants to say then it is not compulsory to answer or down vote

Comment: @sadiqxs . . . As I write this, there are three answers that put the bonus into three *different* tables.  I am not the only one confused about the data structure.  The OP would do well to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` for this purpose like

```
UPDATE `tablename` a 
JOIN 
(
SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
    `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
) tab ON a.`userid` = tab.`userid`       
set a.Bonus = 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$query = "UPDATE user 
          SET bonus=$some_bonus 
          WHERE id IN (
          SELECT userid from (select userid,sum(points) as total 
          FROM table_name GROUP BY userid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10))";
```

here id is the id of the user table given to users and $some_bonus will be the bonus you want to award to the top 10 users.