# How to update top 5 enteries from the chosen top 10 enteries from db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

WRT: [how to insert records for top 10 enteries only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382287/how-to-insert-records-for-top-10-enteries-only)

This is more refined question.

I have gathered top 10 users for specific task. Using the query given below.

```
mysql_query("SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
    `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Now , I need to award bonues to the top 3 gathered users only, out of these selected top 10. I am not getting the idea , on how to write query for this purpose.

The top 3 bonuses are different for  top 3
1: First user gets 1000 points 
2: 2nd user gets 500 points 
3: 3rd user gets 100 points

I need to update one field in tablename = user , field name = points.

To update the bonus i am using the below query(general query):

```
  $Db1->query('UPDATE user SET points=points+'.$rate.' 
WHERE userid = '.$credituser);
```

I hope this question is well elaborated as per the community standards.

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Working on a pure MySQL version.*

As you've PHP tagged, I'll incorporate that into my answer :)

(Ps: Don't use `mysql_*`. As OP used `mysql_*`, my answer will)

- Fetch the results
- Loop through the results
- Update the results depending on their position

```
$objGet = mysql_query("SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
    `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10");

if( mysql_num_rows($objGet) ) {
  $intIteration = 1;
  while( $arrResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($objGet) ) {
     switch($intIteration) {
        case 1 :
          mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET points = points + 1000 WHERE userid = ". $arrResults['userid']);
        break;
        case 2 :
          mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET points = points + 500 WHERE userid = ". $arrResults['userid']);
        break;
        case 3 :
          mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET points = points + 100 WHERE userid = ". $arrResults['userid']);
        break;
        default:
         //No idea.
         //Not in the top 3.
        break;
     }
     $intIteration++;
  }
} else {
  //No users.
}
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, This is has worked perfect as per my needs.